# Is it possible to combine cordova and android ndk?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, android-ndk, cordova

I want to implement a cordova packaged app in javascript and use c-code for some high performance operations.

Is it possible to write a cordova plugin which then calls into android-ndk using jni?

If yes: How should I set up such a project? Is there anything special I should be aware of before starting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it successfully on one of my project. Just make a plugin which map your javascript code to your java code. Then your java code will call a C code trough jni.

Comment: Thank you :) glad to hear that is is straight forward!

Comment: If that helps, feel free to refer to the [Moodstocks PhoneGap demo app](https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-phonegap-demo-app/tree/master/android#readme) for Android, that precisely follows this pattern - the underlying Moodstocks SDK is written in C and wrapped within a JNI wrapper.

Comment: any example or sample project to see how the structure of the plugin folder should be done with the jni interface and library?

Comment: Did you ever get an example? I'm trying to get a plugin to work with .so files and it has been taking me days with no results.